# Stringer - Running 2x4s on top of the dry wall connected to the wall studs behind

Tags: mounting, studs, bolts

I need to mount two vertical strips (blue color in the picture below ) which will hold shelves that can support roughly 400lbs of weight in total. I want to mount this in the center position of the wall. I need roughly a 32" spacing between the two vertical strips.

The studs behind my wall (light brown color in the picture below) have a really odd spacing leaving a giant 26" gap in the center between two of the studs. There are three studs (each spaced 16" apart from each other) on either side of that 26" gap.

I am planning to do a stringer setup by running three 2x4 studs (black color in the picture below) horizontally across the studs and then I can choose any custom centered position to mount the two vertical strips. There will be at least one wall stud on either side of the vertical strip that will have a mechanical connection (red color in the picture below). The vertical strips have three holes which will connect to the three horizontal studs.

Is this a good way to handle this project or is there a better way? What kind of lag bolts would you recommend to mount the horizontal studs to the wall studs in this setup?

[image: Project Diagram]

Thanks!

Comment: I presume your 2x4 stringers will be mounted on the flat (4" tall, 2" deep), right? In general I'd think this would be a pretty good set up. I would probably use 2 3" framing nails at each joint, however, if you need to use lag bolts to make it removable, I'd think that a 1/4" bolt at each joint should be sufficient, considering the number of bolts you've got. I'm sure someone will be along shortly to confirm or deny that, though.

Comment: @FreeMan - Yes that is right the 4" side will rest flat on the wall and it will essentially extend 2" forward from the edge of the wall. I am considering using a lag bolt or possibly Spax powerlags.